# C/Python: Undefined behavior from C code, dir() causing a TypeError

Tags: python, c

I am testing a module that I rewrote from C to Python and having one of the stranger bugs I've seen in my career. The offending Python code with tests is just three lines:

```
# MATCHERS is a list of compiled regular expression objects defined as a
# global in the top level of the module
print dir(MATCHERS[0])
# diff.Differ is a class implemented in C with thed Python API; zoneA/B Words are
# lists and CompareLines, isJunk, and SetStaticLine are functions
differ = diff.Differ(zoneAWords, zoneBWords, CompareLines, isJunk, SetStaticLine)
# Causes a TypeError
dir(MATCHERS[0])
```

These three lines produce the following output:

```
['__class__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'findall', 'finditer', 'flags', 'groupindex', 'groups', 'match', 'pattern', 'scanner', 'search', 'split', 'sub', 'subn']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Diff.py", line 1032, in <module>
    main()
  File "Diff.py", line 1019, in main
    diffs = CompareFiles(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
  File "Diff.py", line 584, in CompareFiles
    print dir(MATCHERS[0])
TypeError: eqTest must be a function
```

Printing the dir() of the compiled regular expression object works fine before the object written in C is created, but afterward simply taking the dir() causes a TypeError. As far as I know, there is no way for dir() to cause a TypeError. The TypeError and message associated with it are from my code as part of the customized setter function for the object's eqTest field, but a call to dir() does not, of course, try to set eqTest to anything; it has already been successfully set in the previous line.

This all leads me to believe that something went wrong in the C code to produce such strange behavior. My current hypothesis is a buffer overflow; writing past the bounds of an array changed something that is causing these errors. (Asking MATCHERS[0] to match a string simply crashes Python with no error message) I've been going over the initialization code for a while and just thought I would check if there is anything else that could be causing this.

My code is too long to include here and is on Pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/0Jj5xhD4); you can ignore everything after line 434 as it hasn't been executed yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be that your `Differ_init` function does *not* return `-1` when the initialization in `setup_differ` fails.

Your `setup_differ` calls `py_differ_set_eqTest`:

```
static int py_differ_set_eqTest(DIFFER* self, PyObject* value, void* closure)
{
    PyObject* tmp;

    TYPE_CHECK(PyFunction_Check, "eqTest must be a function");
    ASSIGN_MEMBER_NAME(self, value, eqTest);
    return 0;
}
```

Where the `TYPE_CHECK` macro is:

```
#define TYPE_CHECK(typeChecker, msg) if (value != Py_None && !typeChecker(value)) \
    {PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, msg); return -1;}
```

The problem is that the `setup_differ` does not check whether `py_differ_set_eqTest` succeeds or fails, and your `Differ_init` returns `0` even if it failed.

Now when you call `dir`, it correctly prints the attributes but before returning it probably checks for exceptions, and sees the `TypeError` that was raised by `TYPE_CHECK` and raises it.

to fix this every function should return a value so that you can determine if an exception was raised or not, and the `Differ_init` should return -1 if `setup_differ` failed.

Comment: Okay; I didn't know exceptions worked that way. Now I get the TypeError as expected when initializing the Differ. The function I am supplying as eqTest is also written in C so it fails the PyFunction_Check I am applying.

Comment: It looks like the check I wanted was PyCallable_Check; using that solves my problem completely.

Comment: @dpitch40I Exceptions are explained [here](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/exceptions.html). In particular " If returning due to an error, it is important to indicate to the caller that an error has been set. If the error is not handled or carefully propagated, additional calls into the Python/C API may not behave as intended and may fail in mysterious ways."